# How to pivot a query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

i've the following table:

```
Year, Name, Revenue, Qty
```

I would like a result table with

> Name, Revenue2012, Qty2012, Revenue2013, Qty2013

How to do in Sql for MySql ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try anything?  This concept has been covered in SO.  Just google it.

Comment: Since all your columns are available at design time, you can use cross-tab with `CASE` clauses.

Comment: select * from table pivot ( max(qty) for revenue IN (...)) as vijj;   in sql-server

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi that is not MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a PIVOT function but you can get the result using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select name,
  sum(case when year = 2012 then revenue else 0 end) revenue2012,
  sum(case when year = 2012 then qty else 0 end) qty2012,
  sum(case when year = 2013 then revenue else 0 end) revenue2013,
  sum(case when year = 2013 then qty else 0 end) qty2013
from yourtable
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php you can display it however you want:

```
$table=mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT *
FROM table
");

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Revenue2012</th>
<th>Qty2012</th>
<th>Revenue2013</th>
<th>Qty2013</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>". $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $row['Revenue'] . $row['Year'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $row['Qty '] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $row['Revenue'] . $row['Year'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>". $row['Qty '] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: OP explicitly stated: "*How to do in **Sql** for MySql ?*" (emphasis is mine).